# ResourceReader with Localization?

Tags: c#, localization

In my project we had some resources files (.resources) and we were using `ResourceReader` to parse these and generate some XML files.
The fact is that now we have some localization and the "norm" seems to be :

```
MyResource.resources (default one)
MyResource.en-GB.resources
MyResource.en-US.resources
MyResource.fr-FR.resources
MyResource.de-DE.resources
```

I used "seems to be" because I didnt find anything, on the internet, that would define "officialy" this norm... but in my team, they say this is the official norm we have to follow.

The point is that `ResourceReader` doesn't consider the localization and I'd like to know if there is a tool that will do a lot of work for us ?
I dont really know what I can expect from this Class which could be some simple features and some very complete one (return in which locale a certain ID a available, etcetc...)
If nothing is available that would sound surprising to me but I can do it myself, it will just be long and, necessarily, less optimized... :/

Comment: Hard to guess what you mean by "norm", those are not languages often picked by Japanese programmers.  ResourceManager is a class that makes this easy, as long as you use satellite assemblies.

Comment: Yep, ResourceManager was exactly what I was looking for :) I used this   article http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Localization.aspx